# Sweetalert2 displays for a second and then disappears

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert2

I have a form with a submit button. The button has the following:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name='submit' \ 
onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure? This operation cannot be undone!\")">Submit</button>
```

Now, i'm trying to convert the confirm to sweetalert2.

I got this going

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function confirm(){
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "This operation cannot be undone!",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes'
})
}
</script>
```

and the submit button has been changed to this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name='submit' \ 
    onclick='confirm()'>Submit</button>
```

Now...it kinda works. The popup shows up for a second and then the page refreshes and disappears. The form is submitting to itself. Obviously, I don't want this to happen. I want it to stay on the screen, once the user hits the confirm button it can do whatever it needs to do.

Comment: it is because you call the function but you don't stop event. Your button is submit so js function is invoked but submit event continue. You need to add `return false` on the end of your confirm function.

Comment: So..I did try that, but then when I hit confirm, it doesn't submit the form

Comment: So you will have to submit the form using javascript once the swal is completed

Comment: yes it is because stop submit event and wait for user choice. You need create callback in sweetalert for button ok what will happen.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without having to submit the form using js? I couldn't find a way to submit to self using javascript. Also, I have multiple forms that I want that invoke that function without having to write a js submit for each and every one of them.